# Two Outlets Not Getting Electricity

Tags: electrical, receptacle

In my garage I have four outlets, two on each side wall and the breaker panel on the inside wall. The ones furthest away from the panel both went dead a couple days ago with nothing that I could find as the culprit. When I check the wires hooked up to the outlets themselves, I get a reading of zero. The outlets that are between each of those and the breaker, which they are fed from, still work just fine though. Any help with this would be appreciated.

I am rather new to doing work myself, so if I'm not describing what's happening in an effective way, please don't hesitate to ask me for clarification.

EDIT: So I took off the covers of the outlets I thought fed into them based on what I saw in my attic, and it doesn't look like they lead into the dead outlets. I got back up into my attack and am now confused as to where all these wires are going. I think, until I take down all the plywood in my garage I'm at a standstill. Since that was already on my to-do list, I'll probably work on that tomorrow. Also, I just realized there is an outlet on the outside of the house that isn't working. I have a theory that it's the first in the line of the three that are out which may be the culprit of it all. Going to investigate it tomorrow morning and will edit my post then.

Comment: Do any of the outlets have a "test" and "reset" button (AFCI or GFCI)?

Comment: are those daisy chained, check on the last working and its output to next outlet. wires do not suddenly break, but the connections do

Comment: No GFCI on any of the outlets. And I'm not sure how exactly they are wired up. When I get into the attic, I see yellow cables running down into the first outlet in each line from the breaker box, then I see another set coming up and moving on to the second outlet.

Answer (score 1):

It is the good outlet *before* the bad one.

The incoming wires there are fine, which is why it works.  It's the outgoing wires at that outlet which are having a problem.

It is extremely unlikely to be a wire failing randomly inside the wall.

Comment: Yes, both good outlets are before the bad ones. This is happening on opposite walls in my garage where each wall has two outlets and the second one for each is not working. They both stopped at the same time a few days ago.

Answer (score -2):

With electricity you have your power at the beginning of the wires.  It goes to the end as long as the wire is complete.

Where it stops is where the wire is broken.

Two ways of connecting outlets are by the screws(good) or by the push in holes, faster but prone to give problems.

Turn off the power and check the power is off, do not want to find you turned off the wrong breaker.  It can hurt.

Remove the outlets from their boxes and check the connections are tight.  If you used the push in option, this is a good time to do it right.

If the outlets check out, you will need to check the wires/cables in the wall for any fried mice/nails/axes.

Comment: They are screw types and the connections are good. When I test the wires themselves at the connectors, neither outlets lines have electricity going through them. It just seems odd that two outlets at the ends of their respective lines would both go dead at the same time. My next step is going to be pulling all the plywood off to check the wires. Which I need to do anyway for another project.

Comment: @AaronE What about the outlet before the power stops - what about the connection where the power is supposed to go from the 2nd towards the 3rd outlet?